# Keep check_box_tag selected when filtering

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a list of items that a user can filter on by selecting a check-box in the sidebar. At the moment, I'm having two issues:

1. When selecting a checkbox, it renders the correct page but does not keep the checkbox selected.
2. Because it's not keeping a checkbox selected, I cannot select multiple ones at the same time.

**Controller**:

```
def index
  @items = Item.all
  if params[:search] 
    @items = Item.search(params[:search])
  else
    @items = Item.all
  end
end
```

**Model**:

```
def self.search(search)
  where('title ILIKE ? OR description ILIKE ? OR category ILIKE ? OR stage ILIKE ?', "%#{search}%","%#{search}%","%#{search}%","%#{search}%")
end
```

**View**:

```
<%= form_tag(items_path, :method => "get", id: "search-form") do %>
  <%= check_box_tag("search", "Pre-Launch", false, :onclick => "javascript: search-form.submit();") %> Pre-Launch <br>
  <%= check_box_tag("search", "Post-Launch", false, :onclick => "javascript: search-form.submit();") %> Post-Launch <br>
<% end %>
```

When on page: http://localhost:3000/items?search=Pre-Launch, then the "Pre-Launch" tag should be selected (currently isn't).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you:

1. Make the form remote
2. Attach an `.on 'ajax:success'` event handler to the form
3. Add `respond_to do |format|` block to your controller to render the appropriate HTML (full page on HTML, search results on JS)
4. In your `ajax:success` handler, insert the returned HTML into the DOM

And Bob's your uncle...